# Converting a Postscript font to TrueType

Tags: postscript, truetype

How do I convert a Postscript font to TrueType font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't try to do this really. The font technologies are quite different and making a good quality version of the original would require input from a typographer to properly hint the font.

However, fontforge can do what you want I believe.